# Why are 'suggested edits' being left for weeks?

Tags: discussion

There are 'suggested edits' sitting in the queue waiting to be approved (or rejected) dating back to January 9th. Anyone with +1000 reputation can (and should) approved, improve, or reject these edits.

When new users spend their time to help improve a post, they should be acknowledged for their efforts; not ignored and their contribution wasted. It's a terrible waste of waste of the time and resources of someone who is reaching out to help. Please keep an eye and act on the suggested edit queue.

Answer (score 4):

I am one of the people with +1000 reputation.  I am sorry that we do not seem to review edits quickly enough to meet your standards.

I disagree with your assertion that anyone with +1000 reputation can (and should) approve, improve, or reject edits.  To be clear, here are SQA's instructions to reviewers, verbatim: "**Approve edits you know are correct; reject those you know are wrong. Leave ambiguous edits for other users to judge**."  Of the 13 reviewers with +1000 reputation, there may some who do not know whether a particular edit is correct or wrong.

It is also possible that some reviewers are too busy to review edits quickly enough to meet your standards, or that an edit does not seem important enough to be processed quickly.  I have reviewed and approved many edits in the past few weeks.  Some were typographical or grammatical corrections.  I am in favor of making those kinds of corrections, but I do not believe reviewing them is so urgent that they must be reviewed immediately. For someone who expects instant gratification, waiting for the review of an edit may be disappointing.  I do not believe, however, that the delay will be wasteful.

In any case, I am in favor of acknowledging the contributions of all users, new and old.  I pledge to review edits more quickly.

Comment: My post was only to note that there is a valuable feature which seemed to be largely underused. Sometimes these features (the suggested edit queue) are not easily discovered so I want to assure their significance is understood. The rare user who comes here to improve the site this early are *potentially* valuable contributors for a long time to come. Whether that user returns or not depends largely on their first experience.

Answer (score 2):

Too many useless edits, minor typo fixes without any real value, grammar changes, etc.
It's not worth the effort to review and make a judgement on approving or rejecting.